# How to force requests use the certificates on my ubuntu system

Tags: ssl, python-requests

I'm using a self-signed cert for debug purpose.

```
$ cp hbrls-server.cert /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
$ update-ca-certificates
```

After that, I can see `hbrls-server.pem` in `/etc/ssl/certs/`. But `requests` still raises the SSLError.

If I specify the cert like this: `requests.get('https://blabla', verify='/etc/ssl/certs/hbrls-server.pem')`, it will be OK.

And `python -m requests.certs` returns `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/certifi/cacert.pem`.

How can I make `requests` to use the certs on the system. I'm working on dockerize sth, and would not like to see that `verify=path-to-cert` in my code.

**EDIT:** ubuntu 12.04, python 2.7.3, requests 2.7.0

Comment: Which distribution are you using? On 14.04 `python -m requests.certs` returns `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`.

Answer (score 27):

You can set the environment variable `REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE` so you don't have to modify your code:

```
export REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/hbrls-server.cert
```

Source: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification

Comment: I prefer using `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` which includes both certificates provided by Ubuntu distribution and certificates added by user (`/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/`).

Comment: @and please post this as a separate answer so I can upvote it!